# How to set up WCF Data Services with username/password and certificates?

Tags: wcf, security, wcf-data-services, wif

I have a application where I want to connect to a server using WCF DS with username/password. In addition I want each client to also have a certificate (different for each client). How can I solve this in the most simple way? It must be simple to deploy new certificates to the client.